# Classic ASP Database Type Mismatch '800a000d' Error on IIS8/7.5 but not IIS6

Tags: iis, iis-7, asp-classic, iis-6, iis-8

I'm migrating a horribly written Classic ASP application from IIS6 to IIS8. The error "Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a000d' Type mismatch" is now happening with the results from a database query:

```
if rs.Fields("ValidDays") > 0 then
```

This cast function fixes the application:

```
if cSng(rs.Fields("ValidDays")) > 0 then
```

Is there a global way to enable the old behavior? This is going to effect a number of applications that are going to be rewritten in the next year.

Comment: The *"Old behaviour"*? If it returns a `Type mismatch` now then something in the data has changed `rs.Fields("ValidDays")` should contain a numeric value, if it doesn't you will get a `Type mismatch` error, it's not simple. go check your data source, the provider you are using etc.

Comment: The data is the same. Going to check the datasource.